# Jqplot Line Graph with hover on line effect

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I have jqplot line graph with y axis as amount and x axis as date.
I need to make details of amount being displayed on hovering over the line of the graph.
If anybody know please replay.
Thanx....

Answer (score 3):

Did you try **Highlighter** plugin?

http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/cursor-highlighter.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.highlighter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.cursor.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" hrf="../jquery.jqplot.min.css" />

$(document).ready(function(){
var line1=[['23-May-08', 578.55], ['20-Jun-08', 566.5], ['25-Jul-08', 480.88], ['22-Aug-08', 509.84],
  ['26-Sep-08', 454.13], ['24-Oct-08', 379.75], ['21-Nov-08', 303], ['26-Dec-08', 308.56],
  ['23-Jan-09', 299.14], ['20-Feb-09', 346.51], ['20-Mar-09', 325.99], ['24-Apr-09', 386.15]];
 var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
  title:'Data Point Highlighting',
  axes:{
    xaxis:{
      renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
      tickOptions:{
        formatString:'%b&nbsp;%#d'
      } 
    },
    yaxis:{
      tickOptions:{
        formatString:'$%.2f'
        }
    }
  },
  highlighter: {
    show: true,
    sizeAdjust: 7.5
  },
  cursor: {
    show: false
  }
 });
});
```